# Adding Apple/Caramel to Brown Ale

Tags: fermentation, fruit

Fellow home brewer here with a question. My buddies and I are looking at making an Apple Caramel Brown Ale for this fall but are having trouble agreeing on a way to add the apple and caramel.

We'd like a strong apple taste and sneaky end hit of caramel to overpower the malt. We're using DME. We don't have an official recipe just yet so we're open to suggestions!

How should we add the apple? I've read suggestions such as adding during the boil, freezing it, cooking and freezing. What do you do to get optimum apple taste? We want people to know there's apple in the beer but not have it taste like apple cider. More apple, less sugar if possible. Also, how much do we add in a 5 gal batch?

Thanks!

Comment: Cider/juice is probably your best bet. You should look into "graff" recipes to get a better idea of what you need for your recipe. I think Mr. Beer even has couple a graff kits.

Comment: While I have not done one myself I just listened to an episode of Dr. Homebrew where they made one. Here is the recipe: http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=271466 Here is the podcast: http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/post387/

Answer (score 1):

I have a few friends that made an apple flavoured beer, they added some apple pulp to the boil, and then added apple slices to the secondary.

Regarding the caramel, I'd add it at the end of the boil, just to quickly flash sanitise it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the apples (seems weird to me to put apples in beer), but for the caramel:

Just finished some [abbey style beer with caramel (recipe in German)](http://meinsudhaus.de/bier-rezepte/obergaerige-biere/karamell-klosterbier/). For that I heated 500g regular sugar in batches in a pan until it turned brown and caramelized, then added water, and added everything at the end (last 15 minutes) of the boil, so that it mixes well with the wort.

The end result was a quite sweet and strong beer.